# does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This code hides the broken image but unfortunately it does not work in IE.

```
(function() {
        var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        i = 0, len = img.length;
        for(; i < len; i++) { 
            img[i].onerror = function() {
              this.style.visibility= 'hidden';
            }
        }
}());
```

Please tell me what the error.

Comment: Is it because you don't assign the `onerror` handler until _after_ the `onerror` event has occurred?

Comment: You can format code simply by indenting it an extra four spaces (or highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button).

Comment: @nnnn that is likely to be the reason. Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Doctype: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score 3):

Is it because you don't assign the `onerror` handler until after the `onerror` event has occurred?

For most purposes I probably wouldn't recommend inline event handlers, but for this particular purpose you could try:

```
<img src="..." onerror="this.style.visibility='hidden';">
```

(I know it would be a pain to have that on every img tag, but I think it would be more likely to work.)

Comment: Yes, well that would make it just one of a long list of things that work in browser _X_ but not browser _Y_...

Comment: Yes, but I have a lot of pictures on the site are loaded from our partners

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right - also for Internet Explorer. The problem is the place where you run your code (we don't see it here). If it is at the end of the page, it might happen that some of the images are already loaded and the `onerror` event simply won't happen. You can easily test it with the solution nnnnnn has suggested (inline script). However to find a right and  solution (for IE) and not to modify every img inline - you could try to apply verification on some image attributes like `complete`. The problem is to find a right place to run such test. `onload` seem to be the proper one, but you will have similar problem like with `onerror` - to define the event before image is loaded. Eventually you can do a bit dirty trick - by running your loop with some delay (`setTimeout`) - and execute such code from window.onload. So the code could look like this:

```
(function() {
        var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        i = 0, len = img.length;
        for(; i < len; i++) { 
            if(!img[i].complete) {
              this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        }
})();
```

Run this code only for IE. On Chrome `img[i].complete` can give true for broken image link.